# SJCL not working correctly in Rhino under Java, while same script behaves as expected in sample PHP script

Tags: javascript, encryption

Update:
This works

```
public static void main(String[] args){
try {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = mgr.getEngineFactories();
        System.out.println("Available script engines:");
        for (int i = 0; i < factories.size(); i++) {
            ScriptEngineFactory factory = factories.get(i);

            String engine = factory.getEngineName();
            String language = factory.getLanguageName();

            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Language: " + language);
            System.out.println("Engine: " + engine);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        }
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("ECMAScript");
        File script_file = new File("web/js/sjcl.js");
        Reader reader = new FileReader(script_file);
        engine.eval(reader);
        String script = "function decode(encoded_value){"
                + "var decoded_value = sjcl.decrypt('asdf',encoded_value);"
                + "return decoded_value;}"
                + "function encode(plain_text){"
                + "var encoded_value = sjcl.encrypt('asdf', plain_text);"
                + "return encoded_value;}";
        engine.eval(script);
        Invocable invocableEngine = (Invocable) engine;

        String plain_text = "admin";
        String cypher_text = (String) invocableEngine.invokeFunction("encode", plain_text);
        String plain_text_return = (String)invocableEngine.invokeFunction("decode", cypher_text);
        System.out.print("plain_text="+plain_text+"\ncypher_text=" +cypher_text + "\nplain_text_return=" + plain_text_return+"\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I use `request.getParameter()` for getting the encrypted value from the client (browser) I don't get expected result (the password is decoded as some junk):

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("ECMAScript");
        String filePath = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "js/sjcl.js";
        File script_file = new File(filePath);
        Reader reader = new FileReader(script_file);
        engine.eval(reader);
        String script = "function decode(encoded_value){"
                + "var decoded_value = sjcl.decrypt('asdf',encoded_value);"
                + "return decoded_value;}";
        engine.eval(script);
        Invocable invocableEngine = (Invocable) engine;
        String encoded_un = (String) request.getParameter("pass");
        String un = (String) invocableEngine.invokeFunction("decode", encoded_un).toString();
```

Please help. I'm at my wit's ends now.

---

I am using SJCL to encrypt few request parameters sent from the Browser and trying to decrypt the same in my Java action class (Struts framework) by running SJCL on the server using Rhino.
I'm using the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` functions provided by sjcl.js and hard-coding the password/key for testing purpose.
The script throws an error like `javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Malformed URI sequence.` in this portion of the sjcl.js code:
`sjcl.codec.utf8String={
    fromBits:function(a){
        var b="",c=sjcl.bitArray.bitLength(a),d,e;
        for(d=0;d<c/8;d++){
            if((d&3)===0)e=a[d/4];
            b+=String.fromCharCode(e>>>24);
            e<<=8
            }
            return decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(escape(b)))
        },`

When I change the `escape` to `encodeURI` function the scripts runs without any error but the decoded value is incorrect.
I tested the same thing with a simple PHP application and it shows expected results.

Any help would be awesome :)

PS: I don't mind trying out other javascript encryption libraries.

Comment: Probably off topic, but: In most cases a JavaScript encryption lib is not what you want. Because most coders want to use it in order to protect data while they are sent to a server. For that you need SSL. Javascript libs like SJCL are necessary, if you want the user to encrypt content that the server cannot decrypt! At least not without the user sending the password along.

Comment: I've got pure Java code running for decrypt (0.8 and higher, adata was not evaluated). It runs using Jackson for JSON and Bouncy Castle for CCM mode decryption. Interested in an alternative answer?

Comment: @nfecher We are planning to use SSL in the next version of the software. For now, it just doesn't seem good to send the username/password in raw along with the request (even though it is an internally hosted application) so trying to obfuscate it a bit at least till it the request reaches the java layer.

Comment: @owlstead alternative answer?

Comment: Well, I'm working on a SJCL compatible library in Java, so you may not need Rhino if you keep to Java. Mind you that I'm currently not feeling so well, so it may have to wait until I can release it, I could drop the untested code somewhere somehow.

Comment: @owlstead I found the problem with using SJCL on Rhino. Some js functions like 'escape' don't seem to work on the server side and need to be replaced to their server side equivalent like 'decodeURIComponent' (am I correct?). Any ideas on how I make the SJCL code Rhino compatible? Or is there a version that may run on the server?

Comment: @owlstead would be awesome if I can get your code at least for the testing purposes. Is it hosted somewhere? How can I get it?

Comment: Now it is, but it is extremely unstable yet (and a few nodes too deep): https://github.com/owlstead/JSCL/tree/master/JSCL/JSCL

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for the code. I got the SJCL running in Rhino after a few fixes so did not yet try out your library. However, I'm still stuck cuz it wont work when I try to use request parameters :(